# PHPmyadmin Xampp error : #1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I Work with xampp localhost and see this error in PHPMyAdmin:

1- my list of database is empty :

```
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

2- see this error :

```
Could not save recent table

#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_recent' doesn't exist

 SELECT `prefs` FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_table_uiprefs` WHERE `username` = 'root' AND `db_name` = 'cms' AND `table_name` = 'cms_users'

MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs' doesn't exist
```

How do i fix this ?!

Comment: go to phpmyadmin config.inc.php file and apply some changes, you can read the manual for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table exists on your database.
Try doing the Create Table syntax all over again.
Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
     id INT,
     data VARCHAR(100)
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved the issue for xampp on windows 
   SELECT `prefs` FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_table_uiprefs` WHERE `username` =

First make sure schema phpmyadmin and all pma tables are available.

If not, you can import xampp/phpMyAdmin/examples/create_tables.sql. the tables should be available now.

If the problem still persists, check whether there is "__" in the table name.
e.g. If that is the case ( In my case), you need to edit xampp/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs'; // earlier
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';  // edited
```

xampp error #1146 should be gone now.